What is the pressure near the end of the siphon tube inside water?
Consider a standard siphon Tube as shown

What is the pressure at point O in the figure?
A continuous streamline is there from A to O to B to C to D (correct me if I m wrong)
Applying Bernoulli’s and continuity equation from A to O and from O to C all gives different and weird results
Say efflux velocity at C is v then the velocity at O should also be v ..
So pressure at C is P atm, pressure at O will be less than P atm by its height
But pressure at O should have been greater than P atm because now considering point A and going down, pressure increase in a liquid vessel
How did I generate a paradox?

Long story cut short.. what is the pressure at O?
Going through one way leads to lower pressure than P atm and other way, a higher pressure

If O and C are at same horizontal level, then the pressure at C must be equal to pressure at O. Pressure at point C is not equal to $\rho$gh, because fluid statics does not work near a pipe, where water is entering with considerable velocity.
By bernoulli's  theorem, (h1 is between A and O, h2 is between O and D)
between A and O: PA + $\rho$gh1 = PO + $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$. (This equation means that it is not right to say PO = PA + $\rho$gh1, because we are ignoring the $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$ term. The paradox was created because of this ignored term. It's greater than $\rho$gh1)
between O and C: PO + $\rho$gh2 + $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$ = PD + $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$
PD is PA = atmospheric pressure.
From the above two equations you get the following:
$\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$ - $\rho$gh1 = $\rho$gh2 = PA - PO
From the 2nd and 3rd term in the above equality, you get PO = PA - $\rho$gh2.
If you want the speed of the flow, you can use 1st and 2nd term,
$\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$ = $\rho$g(h1+h2)

Thank you so much

Now consider a case of a container having a small  hole or orifice… the pressure near the right end of orifice is P atm… but pressure to the left of the orifice is different (which we can find using bernouliii ..why such discontinuity or sudden jump in pressure ?

The sudden jump is pressure is due to the sudden increase in speed of fluid. The speed of fluid increases fast from just inside the container to just outside. In fact the speed inside the container is taken to be 0, which is a approximation in calculating the velocity of efflux (v=rt(2gh)). There has to be a force that causes water to accelerate. So the pressure just inside the container has to be more than the outside pressure. This causes net pressure outwards and accelerates the water.
